# Export users from User Profile

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, export

Is there a way to export all user profiles from SP using something other than powershell?

I need a list of all synchronized users from SharePoint.

Comment: You can link to the User Information List via Microsoft Access, then dump to Excel, or where ever, from there.

Comment: @whitehat, that will only give you the users of that site collection, not all synchronized users

Comment: thanks, wasn't sure what he meant by synchronized. which is why i didn't try to answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the info? Why is PowerShell not an option?

Comment: @Matthew. I need to compare the amount of users in SP to AD. Check that the correct values are in place. Also from the most recent update to AD I have 700 less profiles synched. Power shell access is limited to a certain number of IT people and requests take a long time.

Comment: Considering what you are trying to do, PowerShell is your best bet. You can dump the properties into a XML or CSV file and compare them, plus you can use PowerShell against AD as well, then let PowerShell perform the checking, spitting out the differences. If you are seeing different counts it is likely there was a change in AD that your import connection is not seeing.